# Why does Oracle require an alias for columns in a view when dereferencing an object?

Tags: sql, oracle

Why does Oracle require an alias for columns in a view when dereferencing an object?

For example:

```
CREATE VIEW view AS SELECT t.eno, t.workdept.dname, t.salary FROM table t
                                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias
```

(workdept is an object reference)

This can be fixed by changing `t.workdept.dname` to `t.workdept.dname AS alias`.

My question is, why is this enforced? Why not just use the attribute name `workdept.dname` as would happen in an unaliased select e.g:

`SELECT t.eno, t.workdept.dname, t.salary FROM table t`

(This works fine)

Answer (score 3):

First always use aliases.

Second, here is the oracle reason why,  pertaining to views:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8004.htm

> If you omit the aliases, the database derives them from the columns or column aliases in the query. For this reason, you must use aliases if the query contains expressions rather than only column names. Also, you must specify aliases if the view definition includes constraints.

Oracle treats an object reference as an expression not a table column.

Comment: _"Always use aliases"_? There's no need to alias every column every time. You might want to call a column in a view the same as it's called in the table.